# Weird scope error in a module

Tags: perl, inheritance, html-parsing

I am writing a Perl module which inherits from HTML::Parser, and I am getting a compile error I fail to resolve since yesterday. This here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# HTML::Parser : The inheriting module
# Fetches all links and their text from a HTML file

use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::Entities;

package AnchorTextParser;

use base 'HTML::Parser';

our $betweenAnchor;
our $linkAdress;
our %anchorTexts;


sub start {
    my (undef, undef, $attr) = @_;
    if( $attr->{href} && not ($attr->{href} =~ /mailto/i) ) {
        $betweenAnchor = 1;
        $linkAdress = $attr->{href};
    }
}

sub end {
    $betweenAnchor = 0;
}

sub text {
    if( $betweenAnchor ) {
        my $origText;
        (undef, $origText) = @_;
        #print decode_entities($origText) . "\n";
        %anchorTexts{$linkAdress} = decode_entities($origText); 
    }
}

sub getAnchorTexts {
    return\%anchorTexts;
}

1;
```

The error I get when I load the module is:

```
syntax error at AnchorTextParser.pm line 34, near "%anchorTexts{" 
Global symbol "$origText" requires explixit package name at AnchorTextParser.pm line 34.
syntax error at AnchorTextOarser.pm line 36, near "}"
Compilation failed in require at module_loader.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at module_loader.pl line 6.
```

Just in order to avoid any confusion, this is what happens in the module loader:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# HTML::Parser : The test script

use warnings;
use strict;
use AnchorTextParser;
```

This is the first time I write an inheriting module in Perl, so that might very well be where I am doing something wrong. But the error is so nondescript and obviously wrong ($origText is not global, and very clearly defined as "my" .. ), that I couldn't figure out what the error was.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your reference to the `anchorTexts` variable on line 34 by changing the `%` to a `$`:

```
    $anchorTexts{$linkAdress} = decode_entities($origText);
```

Comment: Well, it ended up being even simpler than I thought. Many thanks, it solved the issue.

Comment: Now that line will compile, yay! But it's still going to fail at run time because he imported the `decode_entities` function into the wrong package.

Comment: @tobyink how did I import that in the wrong package? I got the error iirc, but I "solved" it by calling the function with HTML::Entities::decode_entities($origText); How or where should I have importet it? Within the function? Are all overloaded functions part of the base-class scope/namespace?

Comment: Modules that export functions **export them into a package**, not into a lexical scope. (Though now that Perl 5.18 has given us lexical subs, that might start to change.) This means that you should import HTML::Entities *below* the `package` line so that the functions get imported into the AnchorTextParser package. With the import *above* `package`, it will import HTML::Entities into AnchorTextParser's *caller*. (But not reliably. StackOverflow comments are too short to explain why.) `strict` and `warnings` incidentally have entirely lexical scope, so are safe to import *above* `package`.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel Basically, the [`package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) statement should be the first line of your module file: `AnchorTextParser.pm`.  The `use` statements for it should be after.

Comment: thank you for clarifying that. always happy to learn something new about a language =)